# How to format output in R containing both integers and real numbers?

Tags: r, integer, format, output, real-number

The output of my code is following:

```
print(c(ax,bx,cx,dx))
>[1] 232.0000 2.0000 0.6578 1.2356
```

where in all the cases, the first two numbers are integers, and the rest are real. What should I include in the `print` statement, such that the output is:

```
>[1] 232 2 0.6578 1.2356
```

I know this must be very simple, but somehow I could not figure this out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You don't specify where you need this, like in markdown or cuarto. But `sprintf` can handle specific printing of values. In your case: `sprintf("%d %d %.4f %.4f", ax, bx, cx, dx)`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @user2554330, for mentioning using `noquote` like this:

```r
ax = 232.0000 
bx = 2.0000 
cx = 0.6578 
dx = 1.2356
print(noquote(as.character(c(ax,bx,cx,dx))))
#> [1] 232    2      0.6578 1.2356
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could use `as.character` to remove the trailing zeros like this:

```r
ax = 232.0000 
bx = 2.0000 
cx = 0.6578 
dx = 1.2356
print(as.character(c(ax,bx,cx,dx)))
#> [1] "232"    "2"      "0.6578" "1.2356"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Even better:  use `noquote(as.character(c(ax,bx,cx,dx)))` to suppress the quotes.

Comment: @user2554330, thank you for mentioning it! Good idea to use `noquote`!

Answer (score 1):

While I like `noquote`, replacing all trailing zeros will have the same effect:

```
sub("0+$", "", as.character(c(ax,bx,cx,dx)))
```

```
[1] "232"    "2"      "0.6578" "1.2356"
```